# SWF Flow FrameWork DataConverterException while serializing CancellationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am trying to explicitly cancel a TryCatchFinally statement using:

```
`TryCatchFinally executionTask = new TryCatchFinally(){
    @Override
    doTry(){
      //some nested try catch in @Async methods here.
    }`

    @Override
    protected void doCatch(final Throwable e) throws Throwable {
              //All fatal exceptions
              if (e instanceof GameDayExecutionFailureException) {
                  //doSomethin
              } else if (e instanceof CancellationException) {
                   //doSomething
             } else if (e instanceof Exception) {
                   //doSomething
     }

      @Override
            protected void doFinally() throws Throwable {
              //doCleanUp from here.
            }
    };
```

Then inside an @Signal method:

```
executionTask.cancel(null); //tried passing a new RunTime Exception here as well.
```

The problem is, for some reason, after all child ActivityTasks are cancelled and `doFinally()` of the `executionTask` is executed, the workflow rather than gracefully exiting is throwing further `CancellationException`, which is leading to the following stack trace:

```
    com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.DataConverterException: Failure serializing "java.util.concurrent.CancellationException" of type "class java.util.concurrent.CancellationException" when mapping key "null" 
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.JsonDataConverter.throwDataConverterException(JsonDataConverter.java:90)
 at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.JsonDataConverter.toData(JsonDataConverter.java:78) 
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition.throwWorkflowException(POJOWorkflowDefinition.java:177) 
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition.access$300(POJOWorkflowDefinition.java:30) 
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition$1.doCatch(POJOWorkflowDefinition.java:93) at --- continuation ---.(:0) 
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition.execute(POJOWorkflowDefinition.java:67) at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider$WorkflowExecuteAsyncScope.doAsync(AsyncDecider.java:68) 

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper["factory"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingJsonFactory["codec"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper["factory"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingJsonFactory["codec"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper["factory"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingJsonFactory["codec"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper["factory"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingJsonFactory["codec"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper["factory"]->
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingJsonFactory["codec"]->
..
```

I checked and most of the values inside `CancellationException` instance are null (messege,cause) etc.
But, shouldn't the exception be consumed by the doCatch ? Why is it being thrown out again ?

Comment: Why should the workflow exit gracefully?

Comment: Because once the exception is handled and consumed by doCatch, and doFinally has executed there is really no need for the workflow to fail.

Comment: Could you double check that CancellationException is handled and not rethrown. The failure is happening at https://github.com/aws/aws-swf-flow-library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/pojo/POJOWorkflowDefinition.java#L85 which happens when CancellationException wasn't handled. You could put breakpoint into doCatch block of your code and see what causes it to be rethrown.

Comment: I double checked, cancellation exception was being handled. I think after getting handled something was else causing it to be rethrown.
What has fixed the issue is using the Workflow specific generated external client to send the signal, rather than using the [genericClient.signalWorkflowExecution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/generic/GenericWorkflowClientExternal.html#signalWorkflowExecution-com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.generic.SignalExternalWorkflowParameters-)method.